# Protothreading/ Multithreading on Arduino Uno

Tags: c, arduino-uno

I am trying to use protothreads on Arduino Uno. 
I am following https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/12/30/esp32-arduino-using-the-pthreads-library/.

I have downloaded the pthread.h header file and put it in the same directory as my .ino file.

I have changed the #include statement from the tutorial to #include "pthread.h" as the file is present in the same directory as my .ino file.

I am getting the following error:

```
Protothreading_example:11:4: error: 'pthread_t' was not declared in this scope
    pthread_t threads[4];
    ^
Protothreading_example:16:37: error: 'threads' was not declared in this scope
       returnValue = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, printThreadId, (void *)i);
                                     ^
Protothreading_example:16:79: error: 'pthread_create' was not declared in this scope
       returnValue = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, printThreadId, (void *)i);
                                                                               ^
exit status 1
'pthread_t' was not declared in this scope
```

I have two follow up questions:

**1)** Is there a better tutorial source for protothreading on Arduino?

**2)** I need to read data from multiple sensors and process separately. Since Arduino does not support multithreading at the hardware level, I have made another implementation to loop through an array of function pointers with a timer. Is this approach the same as protothreading?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use multithreading? Is it not possible to implement it using a simple loop? Do you have timing constraints?

Comment: Yes. The system needs to perform real time: process audio through a mic, obstacle detection and controlling servos. The idea was to run each on a separate thread to improve performance

Comment: The 8-bit MCU provided in the Arduino Uno is a relatively slow one. Are you sure it can handle all these tasks in the required timing constraints? I would recommend first implementing the tasks individually and see how fast they run. Afterwards you could use either [a FreeRTOS implementation on Arduino](https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library) or even programming on bare-metal C for higher performance. However bare in mind that RTOS implementations have their own processing power overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you mentioned is intended for ESP32, which has a different Arduino core than the Arduino Uno itself. Primarily it contains FreeRTOS, which supplies the underlying mechanisms for this library. It will not work with Arduino Uno as is.

I believe that you do not need multithreading for your application. You can just loop through the sensor readings and process it in the end of your loop. A step forward to concurrency would be to use a [simple scheduler](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Arduino_FreeRTOS library to create multiple tasks that can run concurrently. The reason I am not calling it a thread is that the terminology used for RTOS is tasks. ESP-IDE also have the wrapper of thread written over FreeRTOS you can easily used the original API of FreeRTOS to achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34559634)